# Is it safe to delete .dsp and .dsw files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've been given a Visual Studio project which has come with the following files:

- myproj.def
- myproj.dsp
- myproj.dsw
- myproj.idl
- myproj.vcxproj
- myproj.vcxproj.filters

After reading the [Project and Solution Files Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/project-and-solution-files?view=vs-2019) it says for *Projname.vcxproj*:

> The project file. It stores information specific to each project. (In earlier versions, this file was named Projname.vcproj or Projname.dsp.) For an example of a C++ project file (.vcxproj), see Project Files.

And [this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/using-visual-studio) says:

> For convenience, Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 provides a project file for each sample. This file has the DSP extension. An Allsamp.dsw workspace file is also provided in the main directory so that you can compile all the samples at once from within Visual Studio.

Does that mean that if I have the `.vcxproj` file, I can safely delete the `.dsp` and `.dsw` files?

Assume I do not care to ever recompile using Visual Studio 6.0 in the future.

Comment: Short answer: for .dsw and .dsp files - completely safe! (They've been replaced with, respectively, .sln and .vcxproj files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.sln is equivalent to .dsw in VC6.0

.vcxproj is equivalent to .dsp in VC6.0

As far as I'm concerned ,if you have the .vcxproj file , you can safely delete the .dsp and .dsw files?